# Cleaning variables passed to function using $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, each

I have the following:

```
setup : function(first, middle, last) {

    // Clean input.
    $.each([first, middle, last], function(index, value) {

        ??? = value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    });
```

Is there a way I could get that to work? I've tried to figure out what to substitute instead of `???` (I've tried `this`, `index`, `this[index]`, but can't seem to wrap my head around pointing to the original variables.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Arguments object.

```
setup : function(first, middle, last) {
    var args = arguments;
    $.each(arguments, function(index, value) {
        args[index] = value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/EfHQ2/

Comment: Would it be possible (or a horrible practice) to do `arguments[index]` instead the `each` and overwrite what was given. The purist in me doesn't want to create another variable.

Also is using map like: `arguments = $.map(arguments...` possible if the above isn't a bad practice? Seems like the neatest solution.

Comment: Actually gonna ask it in a new question to get more feedback on overwriting arguments in general. Thanks both of you!

Comment: Also just realized that $.map probably wouldn't work to overwrite since arguments isn't really an array.

Comment: @Ian: Sorry I missed your comments. Fell asleep. :o) I'll take a look at your other question too, but if you're going to do it in an `$.each()` loop, you need to first reference the original `arguments` object. The reason is that since `$.each` invokes the function you give it, it will have its own `arguments` object that isn't useful to you  in this situation. That's why I referenced the original with `args`.

Comment: ...I see from your other question that you already discovered this. :o)

Answer (score 1):

To modify arrays, use `$.map()` instead, and just return the new value:

```
var clean = $.map([first, middle, last], function(value, index) {
    return value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
});
```

Better, use the special `arguments` object (as in [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000352/cleaning-variables-passed-to-function-using-each/5000365#5000365)) in place of building a temporary array:

```
var clean = $.map(arguments, function(value, index) {
    return value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: Since you're using the more generic `$.map()`, you need to flip around the parameters like `(value, index)`. They're opposite of the `.map()` method.